# Excel: Total Count of Cells Across Multiple Worksheets Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets, each worksheet represents a calendar month starting with May_2013 and ending with December_2013. I want to count only the cells within C2-C32 in each worksheet that contains data and omit the cells without data.

I am completely useless when it comes to Excel. Any solutions/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want a formula or a piece of VBA code? if you want a formula, you have to write something like `=count(sheet1!range1)+count(sheet2!range2)+...` (this counts only numbers, if you want to count numbers and text, use `counta` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
=CountIF(C2:C32,"<>"&"")
```

should do what you want.

For multiple pages, do a countIf for each page example -

```
=CountIF('Sheet1'!C2:C32,"<>"&"")+CountIF('Sheet2'!C2:C32,"<>"&"")
```

*This will work to give you the number of cells with values, if you want to add the values together please specify that in your question and I can fix the answer*

Comment: You can also do `=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!C:C, "<>"&"")` so you don't need to specify row numbers.